# Sidekiq service seems to 'sleep', wakes when interacted with

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, sidekiq, ubuntu-server

So, I'm having a hard time understanding why Sidekiq is behaving like this. I use the following sidekiq.service to enable Sidekiq on startup (from [here](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/examples/systemd/sidekiq.service)):

```
#
# systemd unit file for CentOS 7+, Ubuntu 15.04+
#
# Customize this file based on your bundler location, app directory, etc.
# Put this in /usr/lib/systemd/system (CentOS) or /lib/systemd/system (Ubuntu).
# Run:
#   - systemctl enable sidekiq
#   - systemctl {start,stop,restart,reload} sidekiq
#
# This file corresponds to a single Sidekiq process.  Add multiple copies
# to run multiple processes (sidekiq-1, sidekiq-2, etc).
#
[Unit]
Description=sidekiq
# start us only once the network and logging subsystems are available,
# consider adding redis-server.service if Redis is local and systemd-managed.
After=syslog.target network.target

# See these pages for lots of options:
#
#   https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html
#   https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html
#
# THOSE PAGES ARE CRITICAL FOR ANY LINUX DEVOPS WORK; read them multiple
# times! systemd is a critical tool for all developers to know and understand.
#
[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/opt/myapp/current
# If you use rbenv:
# ExecStart=/bin/bash -lc '/home/deploy/.rbenv/shims/bundle exec sidekiq -e production'
# If you use the system's ruby:
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/bundle exec sidekiq -e production

# use `systemctl reload sidekiq` to send the quiet signal to Sidekiq
# at the start of your deploy process.
ExecReload=/usr/bin/kill -TSTP $MAINPID

User=deploy
Group=deploy
UMask=0002

# Greatly reduce Ruby memory fragmentation and heap usage
# https://www.mikeperham.com/2018/04/25/taming-rails-memory-bloat/
Environment=MALLOC_ARENA_MAX=2

# if we crash, restart
RestartSec=1
Restart=on-failure

# output goes to /var/log/syslog
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog

# This will default to "bundler" if we don't specify it
SyslogIdentifier=sidekiq

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

All seems good. The service is active and enabled with no errors. However, after a while, it seems to go to... sleep? Observe the following commands:

```
deploy-user@bach-fa39e9:/etc/systemd/system$ ps -ef | grep sidekiq
deploy+  7994     1 99 13:38 ?        00:00:02 /var/deploy/application/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/bin/sidekiq
deploy+  8006  1643  0 13:39 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto sidekiq
deploy-user@bach-fa39e9:/etc/systemd/system$ ps -ef | grep sidekiq
deploy+  8372  1643  0 13:40 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto sidekiq
deploy-user@bach-fa39e9:/etc/systemd/system$ sudo systemctl status sidekiq
● sidekiq.service - sidekiq
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/sidekiq.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2020-01-08 13:40:47 CET; 3s ago
 Main PID: 8434 (bundle)
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/sidekiq.service
           └─8434 /var/deploy/application/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/bin/sidekiq

Jan 08 13:40:47 bach-fa39e9 systemd[1]: Started sidekiq.
deploy-user@bach-fa39e9:/etc/systemd/system$ ps -ef | grep sidekiq
deploy+  8495     1 74 13:41 ?        00:00:00 /var/deploy/application/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/bin/sidekiq
deploy+  8507  1643  0 13:41 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto sidekiq
deploy-user@bach-fa39e9:/etc/systemd/system$ ps -ef | grep sidekiq
deploy+  8864     1 97 13:42 ?        00:00:04 /var/deploy/application/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/bin/sidekiq
deploy+  8878  1643  0 13:42 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto sidekiq
```

After viewing the status with systemctl, Sidekiq magically comes to life. This is not supposed to happen, because I'd like Sidekiq to listen at all time. Another example, when Sidekiq comes to life after grepping for it (you can even see Sidekiq coming to life after the second command):

```
deploy-user@bach-fa39e9:/etc/systemd/system$ ps -ef | grep sidekiq
deploy+ 18516  1643  0 14:20 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto sidekiq
deploy-user@bach-fa39e9:/etc/systemd/system$ ps -ef | grep sidekiq
deploy+ 18541     1  0 14:20 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/bin/ruby /usr/local/bin/bundle exec sidekiq
deploy+ 18556  1643  0 14:20 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto sidekiq
deploy-user@bach-fa39e9:/etc/systemd/system$ ps -ef | grep sidekiq
deploy+ 18541     1 86 14:20 ?        00:00:02 /var/deploy/application/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/bin/sidekiq
deploy+ 18558  1643  0 14:20 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto sidekiq
deploy-user@bach-fa39e9:/etc/systemd/system$ ps -ef | grep sidekiq
deploy+ 18576     1 89 14:20 ?        00:00:02 /var/deploy/application/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/bin/sidekiq
deploy+ 18588  1643  0 14:20 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto sidekiq
```

I really do not why this is happening or why Sidekiq even 'sleeps'. I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.

Comment: Maybe it's crashing and systemd is restarting it?  Look in the logs.

Comment: @jan-hoi did you figure out what was causing this issue?